CPLD replacement
I want to replace the CPLD of my Audio Card. The IC for replacement is the
ALTERA EPM 7064 SKC44 - 10.
Can i just replace it with a new one or the new one must first be programmed ?
The reason i want to replace it is that i have inject 5 Volts and the CPLD got hot very quickly. I did this because my Card has a problem and i want to diagnose what exactly cause it.
If indeed the CPLD came bad and to replace with a new one must first program it, what can i do ? I am not a professional and i do not know even if somebody out of Audio's Card Company can do this. Then, does the card be useless ?

What is the "Audio Card"? Can u show pictures?

Yes i can show picture. I cannot see here, an option to show pictures, so i will provide a link. But before this, i want to say that there is a new information . I noticed that ecxept the ALTERA EPM 7064 SKC44 - 10 chip, there is an other chip very close to it, that is getting hot too. It is the   P98AB VT244, as i can read in the top side of it. Do you think that maybe it is broken and because of it, the ALTERA also comes hot ? I mean, is there a change if i replace the P98AB VT244, card will fixed (if there is nothing else that, now, i do not know) ?

Something else is that can only find 74LVT244 and SN54LVT244, but i do not know if they are compatible with P98AB VT244.     Picture link is https://www.4shared.com/s/fE7x89AWzge
The two components shown by the arrows. The big for the ALTERA and the small for the P98AB VT244 .

The programming is inside the chip so if you don't have the programming file and you cannot extract the data from the current chip because it is damaged or protected so nobody can clone it, replacing the IC with a working one is useless without the programming data.
If you have the "program" it may not matter whether or not you program the new chip before or after putting it on the board. The problem is more how you either program it before or after.

As i wrote in my comment @Rondo, there is a new information . I noticed that except the ALTERA EPM 7064 SKC44 - 10 chip, there is an other chip very close to it, that is getting hot too. Can you please read it ?

OK Solved. I have replaced the ALTERA by "transplanting" from a "donor" card (exactly the same, but used only for parts)
